# How to get a key if other key contains the word rp

Tags: python, json

I've started with a small project to get better at python. For this project I need to get the user_ids from the people who have the word rp in their title.
I know how to get all the user_id's from the json api response by using the following code:
`[x['user_id'] for x in data['data']]`

but now I want to only get the user_id's of the users that have the word rp in their title. but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

json response from twitch API:

```
{  
   'data':[  
  {  
     'id':'27144974352',
     'user_id':'23308993',
     'game_id':'32982',
     'community_ids':[  
        'af543777-83ec-402d-8245-30da1409e22a',
        'c0294643-085c-4943-94ab-f0e1ba090e23',
        'd74020e4-53af-48c3-b3d1-f23500a490c8'
     ],
     'type':'live',
     'title':'[COMBROS] Джордж Бруйвик - All of this #9',
     'viewer_count':1326,
     'started_at':'2018-01-02T05:36:07Z',
     'language':'en',
     'thumbnail_url':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_igorghk-{width}x{height}.jpg'
  },
  {  
     'id':'27146956464',
     'user_id':'68064974',
     'game_id':'32982',
     'community_ids':[  

     ],
     'type':'live',
     'title':'HYVÄÄ UUTTAVUOTTA // 3.1.18 klo: 12-00 12h Livestream subien kunniaksi! // !subgiveaway',
     'viewer_count':998,
     'started_at':'2018-01-02T12:58:49Z',
     'language':'en',
     'thumbnail_url':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_mrtuomostream-{width}x{height}.jpg'
  },
  {  
     'id':'27147162448',
     'user_id':'58529158',
     'game_id':'32982',
     'community_ids':[  
        '5181e78f-2280-42a6-873d-758e25a7c313',
        'a61f2599-ba45-4391-905c-ca0c8cbf61a6',
        'ff1e77af-551d-4993-945c-f8ceaa2a2829'
     ],
     'type':'live',
     'title':'( English ) Happy New Year | Kaitlyn Maw',
     'viewer_count':781,
     'started_at':'2018-01-02T13:36:32Z',
     'language':'en',
     'thumbnail_url':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_katie-{width}x{height}.jpg'
  },
  {  
     'id':'27147842992',
     'user_id':'69759951',
     'game_id':'32982',
     'community_ids':[  

     ],
     'type':'live',
     'title':'GTARP - Kudo Kai - NoPixel',
     'viewer_count':312,
     'started_at':'2018-01-02T15:24:50Z',
     'language':'en',
     'thumbnail_url':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_vader-{width}x{height}.jpg'
  },
  {  
     'id':'27144250400',
     'user_id':'3345556',
     'game_id':'32982',
     'community_ids':[  
        'ab18bbee-75ed-409d-aba9-8d4e3e2e541a'
     ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For one sub-string:**

```
[x['user_id'] for x in data['data'] if 'rp' in x['title'].lower()]
```

**For more than one sub-string:**

```
[x['user_id'] for x in data['data'] if any(s in x.get('title', '').lower() for s in ['hey', 'hi', 'rp'])]
```

As this becomes complex, here's the normal iteration version of it:

```
ids = []
parts = ['hey', 'hi', 'rp']
for user in data['data']:
    title = user.get('title', '').lower()
    if any(part in title for part in parts):
        ids.append(user['user_id'])
```

Comment: sorry for the big amount of questions but I did this with the viewercount aswell `[x['viewer_count'] for x in data['data'] if any(s in x.get('title', '').lower() for s in ['hey', 'rp'])]` but how would I blacklist people. like I want to get the viewer_counts but not from the person with user_id: 23308993

Answer (score 1):

I would add this as a comment on Omar's comment above but I don't have the rep.

That answer would throw an exception when it hits the last entry in the example JSON, because there is no `'title'` entry.

You would need to do

```
[x['user_id'] for x in data['data'] if 'rp' in x.get('title', '').lower()]
```

Comment: No need to add meta-information to an answer such as "above" (the position of answers is not fixed; Stack Overflow is not a forum!). You could better word it as "Based on @Omar's answer, but this will not throw..."  Not having reputation to comment does not disqualify one from answering *as* a comment.

Comment: but let's say instead of the word rp I want to get the user_id's if the title contains one of the following words: hey, hi, rp. I tried using `[x['user_id'] for x in data['data'] if 'rp' or 'hey' or 'hi' in x.get('title', '').lower()] ` but this doesn't seem to work. @PerlPingu @OmarEinea

Comment: @kappa123 I updated my answer to include more than one sub-string searching. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

try using an 'if' in your existing code

`[x ['user_id'] for x in data['data'] if 'rp' in x['title']]`

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to go with filter method :

One line solution :

```
print(list(filter(lambda x:'rp' in x['title'].lower(),data['data'])))
```

output:

```
[{'user_id': '69759951', 'community_ids': [], 'title': 'GTARP - Kudo Kai - NoPixel', 'thumbnail_url': 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_vader-{width}x{height}.jpg', 'viewer_count': 312, 'started_at': '2018-01-02T15:24:50Z', 'game_id': '32982', 'language': 'en', 'type': 'live', 'id': '27147842992'}]
```

When data is:

```
data={
   'data':[
  {
     'id':'27144974352',
     'user_id':'23308993',
     'game_id':'32982',
     'community_ids':[
        'af543777-83ec-402d-8245-30da1409e22a',
        'c0294643-085c-4943-94ab-f0e1ba090e23',
        'd74020e4-53af-48c3-b3d1-f23500a490c8'
     ],
     'type':'live',
     'title':'[COMBROS] Джордж Бруйвик - All of this #9',
     'viewer_count':1326,
     'started_at':'2018-01-02T05:36:07Z',
     'language':'en',
     'thumbnail_url':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_igorghk-{width}x{height}.jpg'
  },
  {
     'id':'27146956464',
     'user_id':'68064974',
     'game_id':'32982',
     'community_ids':[

     ],
     'type':'live',
     'title':'HYVÄÄ UUTTAVUOTTA // 3.1.18 klo: 12-00 12h Livestream subien kunniaksi! // !subgiveaway',
     'viewer_count':998,
     'started_at':'2018-01-02T12:58:49Z',
     'language':'en',
     'thumbnail_url':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_mrtuomostream-{width}x{height}.jpg'
  },
  {
     'id':'27147162448',
     'user_id':'58529158',
     'game_id':'32982',
     'community_ids':[
        '5181e78f-2280-42a6-873d-758e25a7c313',
        'a61f2599-ba45-4391-905c-ca0c8cbf61a6',
        'ff1e77af-551d-4993-945c-f8ceaa2a2829'
     ],
     'type':'live',
     'title':'( English ) Happy New Year | Kaitlyn Maw',
     'viewer_count':781,
     'started_at':'2018-01-02T13:36:32Z',
     'language':'en',
     'thumbnail_url':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_katie-{width}x{height}.jpg'
  },
  {
     'id':'27147842992',
     'user_id':'69759951',
     'game_id':'32982',
     'community_ids':[

     ],
     'type':'live',
     'title':'GTARP - Kudo Kai - NoPixel',
     'viewer_count':312,
     'started_at':'2018-01-02T15:24:50Z',
     'language':'en',
     'thumbnail_url':'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_vader-{width}x{height}.jpg'
  },


]

}
```